# Loopback Nodejs framework: How do I add Firebase and Parse as models?

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, loopbackjs

I'm looking to add parse.com and firebase.com to my Strongloop Loopback project.  I want them to be REST models.  How do I do this?

edit:  I've enabled the Loopback REST model connector.  I'm faced with creating a REST CRUD schema per this: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/REST+connector

I'd really love it if someone who has done this before for Parse and/or Firebase to share their CRUD REST schema boilerplate here.

Comment: Did you try to setup REST Connector? http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/REST+connector.

Comment: Could you show the schema you've created so far and the issues you have with it?